# How to install pyside2-uic in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python, ubuntu-16.04, pyside2, uic

I've tried installing Pyside2-uic using :

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-pyside2
sudo apt-get install pyside2-tools
```

while I'm converting the .ui file to .py using pyside2-uic still i get error as " ImportError: No module named pyside2uic.driver "

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pyside2-uic", line 28, in <module>
    from pyside2uic.driver import Driver
ImportError: No module named pyside2uic.driver
```

How to resolve this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried these commands and it worked.

```
$ apt-get install wget python-pip python-dev software-properties-common
$ add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt561-trusty
$ apt-get update
$ apt-get install qt56-meta-full
$ . /opt/qt56/bin/qt56-env.sh
$ wget https://bintray.com/fredrikaverpil/pyside2-wheels/download_file?file_path=ubuntu14.04%2FPySide2-2.0.0.dev0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl -O PySide2-2.0.0.dev0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
$ pip install PySide2-2.0.0.dev0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64.whl
$ pyside2-uic
```